# How to stop parent div from stretching in IE7

Tags: css, overflow, parent-child, visible, stretch

```
<style type="text/css">

    .parent 
    {
        width            : 200px;
        height           : 50px;
        background-color : #FFFFCC;
        overflow         : visible;
    }

    .child 
    {
         width            : 255px;
         height           : 30px;
         background-color : #CCCCFF;
    }

</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child Content</div>
</div>
```

It works fine in firefox, but in IE7 the parent div is stretching with the child div. Is there anyway to stop IE7 from stretching the parent div? For some design constraints the divs cannot be positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `<!DOCTYPE>` at the start of the HTML solved the issue.

Internet Explorer apparently defaults to 'quirks' mode if no DOCTYPE is declared!

For further information check,
[CSS quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to give the child the following style:

```
.child 
    {
         width            : 255px;
         position         : relative;
         height           : 30px;
         background-color : #CCCCFF;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer, but for some design constraints, none of the divs can be positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `overflow:visible;` to `overflow:hidden;` on your parent container. Not entirely sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input but, no I am deliberately using overflow:visible in the parent content. Firefox is doing it the way I want it but IE is stretching the parent div.

Comment: But can't you just use width: 255px; on the parent container aswell then? Because I think that's your only option, besides mine and Arrabi's.

Comment: i found this site http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html
it shows exactly what I am trying to achieve. According to the site 
it should only misbehave in IE6. The site is working fine in both firefox and IE7, but when I am using virtually the same code (given above) it keeps stretching the parent div in all IE versions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow. But maybe the solution is to remove  overflow: visible; from the parent container and insert it to the child container?

Comment: Here is a link to look at what is happening,
http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/5876/firefoxjn.png
Can you run the code and check if you are getting the same results?

Comment: I wish I could! But I'm using a Mac so I don't have IE7 available. But it sounds to me that removing overflow:visible; from the parent container and inserting it on the child container should work.

Comment: Nope it isn't working. The only thing that is giving me the result i want is if i set the parent position:relative and the child to absolute. But, as declaring position on the parent starts a new stacking context, I cannot use this solution :-(